# How to specify or target a field from a specific document type in queries or filters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Given:**

1. Documents of two different types, let's say 'product' and 'category', are indexed to the same Elasticsearch index.
2. Both document types have a field 'tags'.

**Problem:**

I want to build a query that returns results of both types, but the documents of type 'product' are allowed to have tags 'X' and 'Y', and the documents of type 'category' are only allowed to have tag 'Z'. How can I achieve this? It appears I can't use product.tags and category.tags since then ES will look for documents' product/category field, which is not what I intend.

**Note:**

While for the example above there might be some kind of workaround, I'm looking for a general way to target or specify fields of a specific document type when writing queries. I basically want to 'namespace' the field names used in my query so only documents of the type I want to work with are considered.

Answer (score 1):

I think field aliasing would be the best answer for you, but it's not possible.
Instead you can use "copy_to" but I it probably affects index size:

```
DELETE /test
PUT /test
{
      "mappings": {
          "product" : {
              "properties": { 
                "tags": { "type": "string", "copy_to": "ptags" },
                "ptags": { "type": "string" }
            }
            },
          "category" : {
              "properties": { 
                "tags": { "type": "string", "copy_to": "ctags" },
                "ctags": { "type": "string" }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /test/product/1
{ "tags":"X" }
PUT /test/product/2
{ "tags":"Y" }
PUT /test/category/1
{ "tags":"Z" }
```

And you can query one of fields or many of them:

```
GET /test/product,category/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "ptags": {
              "value": "x"
           }
        }
    }
}

GET /test/product,category/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
        "query":      "x",
        "fields":     [ "ctags", "ptags" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that in your first example 'product.tags' and 'category.tags' seem to try and find, in each candidate document, a field .product.tags and .category.tags instead of the field .tags in documents of type product/category...

Comment: IMHO it doesn't matter if ES internally search "product.tags" in every document and "category.tags" in every document. The result is OK.
I guess that the second example is equivalent to the first and works the same, but I have no knowledge of internal implementation of ES.

Is it possible that I don't understand your intention precisely?

Comment: That's possible, the point is that if you have two doc types containing a field with the same name and you want to use them differently (for whatever reason) in a query depending on the doctype to which the field belongs, you need to have a way to differentiate between the two. And the obvious approach using dot notation does not seem to work.

Comment: Now I see. I completely rewritten the answer to take your clarification into account.